# How to calculate the expected value of a function with random normally distributed X?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate on MatLab the Expectation for the function e^X where X ~ N(mu,sigma^2). In my example, mu = 0 and sigma = 1.

```
function [E] = expectedval(m,s)
%find E(e^x) with X~N(mu,sigma)
% mu = 0 , sigma = 1

X = normrnd(m,s);
f=exp(X);

mean(f)
```

So by the end I can run expectedval(0,1) to get my solution. The code runs with no issue, but I would like to compile a histogram to analyse the data with several runs. How may I collect this data with some sort of loop?

I'd appreciate any improvement ideas or suggestions!

Comment: The [documentation for `for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) contains many examples.

Comment: Are you aware that an [analytical solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) exists? The result is `exp(m+s^2/2)`

Comment: I am aware, thank you though! My goal was to compare analytical with numerical solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your function just creates one random value for the given mean and variance... so there's actually no point in calculating a mean. On the top of that, the output `E` value is not assigned before the function finishes. The function can therefore be rewritten as follows:

```
function E = expectedval(m,s)
    X = normrnd(m,s);
    E = exp(X);
end
```

If you want to draw a sample from the normal distribution, and use the mean to compute the correct expected value, you can rewrite it as follows instead:

```
function E = expectedval(m,s,n)
    X = normrnd(m,s,[n 1]);
    f = exp(X);
    E = mean(f);
end
```

And here is an example on how to run your function many times with different parameters, collecting the output on each iteration:

```
m = 0:4;
m_len = numel(m);

s = 1:0.25:2;
s_len = numel(s);

n = 100;

data = NaN(m_len*s_len,1);
data_off = 1;

for s = 1:s_len
    for m = 1:m_len
        data(data_off) = expectedval(m,s,n);
        data_off = data_off + 1;
    end
end
```